# Getting ssl certificate using EAB key in certbot and signing in , in angular application

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-dns, acme, certbot-dns-plugin

I want to get the SSL certificate (.crt file) and (.key file) from ACME im facing some problems

Obtaining the SSL Certificate with ACME:

Install an ACME client like Certbot.

Run the following command to register with Google Trust Services using your EAB key:

> certbot register --email  --no-eff-email --server
> "https://dv.acme-v02.api.pki.goog/directory" --eab-kid "<EAB_KEY_ID>"
> --eab-hmac-key "<EAB_HMAC_KEY>"

Replace  with your email address and <EAB_KEY_ID> and <EAB_HMAC_KEY> with the values you copied from Google Domains.

Run the following command to obtain the SSL certificate and private key:

> certbot certonly --preferred-challenges dns-01 --dns-google -d

Replace  with your actual domain name.

This command will use Google Cloud DNS to automatically configure your domain for ACME validation.

I am following these steps while i run this command :

> certbot certonly --preferred-challenges dns-01 --dns-google -d

Im getting   :- Saving debug log to C:\Certbot\log\letsencrypt.log

The requested dns-google plugin does not appear to be installed , I tried installing using `pip3 show certbot-dns-google` still im getting the same error of plugin not installed

I have Windows 10 Os , an py version is 3.12.1 . I installed certbot using the website and also using cmd line : pip install certbot-dns-google to integrate with Nginx server , Im following these following instructions :

Signing an Angular Application for HTTPS with Google Domain and EAB Key
Securing your Angular application with HTTPS using an existing Google domain and EAB key involves setting up HTTPS on Google Domain and then configuring your Angular application to use the obtained certificates. Here's a breakdown of the process:

1. Setting Up HTTPS on Google Domain:
   Login to Google Domains and navigate to your domain.
   Open the "Security" menu and click "Manage SSL certificates".
   If you haven't already, purchase an SSL certificate.
   Expand "Google Trust Services" and click "Get EAB Key". Copy the "EAB Key ID" and "EAB HMAC Key".
2. Obtaining the SSL Certificate with ACME:
   Install an ACME client like Certbot.
   Run the following command to register with Google Trust Services using your EAB key:
   certbot register --email  --no-eff-email --server "https://dv.acme-v02.api.pki.goog/directory" --eab-kid "<EAB_KEY_ID>" --eab-hmac-key "<EAB_HMAC_KEY>"
   Replace  with your email address and <EAB_KEY_ID> and <EAB_HMAC_KEY> with the values you copied from Google Domains.
   Run the following command to obtain the SSL certificate and private key:

certbot certonly --preferred-challenges dns-01 --dns-google -d

Replace  with your actual domain name.
This command will use Google Cloud DNS to automatically configure your domain for ACME validation.
3. Configuring Your Web Server:
Configure your web server (e.g., Apache, Nginx) to serve your website over HTTPS.
Specify the obtained certificate and private key file paths in your web server configuration.
Follow the specific instructions for your chosen web server.
4. Configuring Your Angular Application:
Update your angular.json file to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.
Modify the baseHref property to your HTTPS domain.
Enable the useHash option when running in development mode:
JSON

"build": {
"options": {
"useHash": true
}
}

This ensures proper routing behavior with hash navigation.
5. Building and Deploying:
Build your Angular application for production using the ng build --prod command.
Deploy your built application files to your web server.

Comment: What is the OS and version? What is the Python version? How did you install `certbot`? Are you trying to manually create a certificate or integrate with Apache or Nginx? Did you set up the Google Cloud DNS `dns_google` plugin? [link](https://certbot-dns-google.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I am not sure which instructions you are following but your steps are incomplete. Edit your post with additional details.

Comment: Also, post the relevant entries from the log file.

Comment: Operating system is Windows 11 , and python version is 3.12.1

Comment: I have Windows 10 Os , an py version is 3.12.1 . I installed certbot using the website and also using cmd line : pip install certbot-dns-google  to integrate with Nginx server , Im following these following instructions :  
1. Setting Up HTTPS on Google Domain:
Expand "Google Trust Services" and click "Get EAB Key". Copy the "EAB Key ID" and "EAB HMAC Key".
2. Obtaining the SSL Certificate with ACME:


Run the following command to obtain the SSL certificate and private key:
 
certbot certonly --preferred-challenges dns-01 --dns-google -d <domain>

Comment: Please add details to your post and not in the comments.

Comment: I have added the details in post , please go through

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley for the Quick response. I have mentioned the details in the post , kindly review and advise. Thanks for your support

Comment: Did you notice the changes when I edited your post? I made everything formatted and easily readable. You have just posted big blobs of text that are a challenge to read.

Comment: I have added the DNS TXT on the admin console with name and its key. I have re-run the following command and able to generate the SSL certificate for my frontend application. Tested and working fine now. Thank you so much for your support.  
                                                                                                                        
 Command: certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --eab-kid "your-eab-kid" --eab "your-eab-key" -d yourdomain.com

Comment: I would like to understand - from Frontend to Backend - SSL Certificate - Do I need to use the same SSL certificate or self-signed certificate? Currently, I've deployed both Frontend and Backend applications on the same VM. Hence, it should be localhost. Kindly review and advise. Thank you.